# application.onkey press not working while an infinite loop is running (python accepts that why not vba)

Tags: excel, vba

i am currently studying engineering and for my inf project i decided to do a tetris clone started trying to learn python but sadly my college demands that we use excel vba
anyways we started with 1 single square not a whole element and coded it falling down and then a new one creating and falling down too and so on which using an infinite loop proved quite easy
then for the moving left and right part we decided to use the application.onkey method but quickly realised that for some reason this doesnt work while the loop is active but does while its inactive
any help
its a german school so our comments are in german
here our main code

```
stein.color = 4
stein.posx = 0
stein.posy = 4
'2.3.2:stein im grid einfugen
grid(stein.posx, stein.posy) = stein.color
'2.3.3:grid zeichnen
gridzeichnen
'3  : main loop
Do While gamestate
    '3.1:checken ob platz frei ist
    If checkplatz(stein.posx, stein.posy) Then
        '3.1.1: falls ja dann fallen
        warten (50)
        grid(stein.posx, stein.posy) = 2
        stein.posx = stein.posx + 1
        ' hinweis: im grid schreiben/anzeigen
        grid(stein.posx, stein.posy) = stein.color
        gridzeichnen
    Else:
        '3.1.2:falls nein dann neuen stein erstellen
        '3.1.2.1: aber zuerst muss man checken ob die maximale hohe erreicht wurde (also obwohl er 
        'gerade erst erstellt wurde nicht fallen konnte)
        If stein.posx = 0 Then
            'hinweis: print grid nur damit man besser weiss was der program gemacht hat und ob er 
            'irgendwas falsch gemacht hat
            printgrid
            Exit Do
        End If
        ' 3.1.2.2: falls nicht dann neuen stein erstellen
        ' hinweis:hier braucht man nicht die farbe neu erstellen da momentarn die farbe immer 
        '  gleich(wird sich spater andern)
        stein.posx = 0
        stein.posy = 4
        grid(stein.posx, stein.posy) = stein.color
        gridzeichnen
    End If 
Loop
```

Comment: [*"It's not working"* is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). What is the code supposed to do? What errors do you get? What is going wrong? And what is your question (you didn't ask one yet)? What is `stein`, `grid` etc? Those are no native VBA objects so you need to show the code for those methods/objects/classes.

Comment: Note that VBA does not support multi-threadding. That means you cannot run code simultaneously. Add a `DoEvents` inside your loop to see if that fixes the issue. This will allow other events to occur in this place. If it does not solve your issue there is probably no solution.